# How to convert method or lambda to non-lambda proc

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

As shown in the ruby example below, I can't call a `lambda` with wrong number of arguments as `Proc` created from a `Method` because it is strict about the number of arguments:

```
# method with no args
def a; end

instance_eval(&method(:a))
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

method(:a).to_proc.call(1, 2, 3)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)

method(:a).to_proc.lambda?
# => true
```

How do I get a `Proc` that is not a lambda from either a `Proc` that is or from a `Method`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't convert a method or lambda to a non-lambda proc.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @WallyAltman The calling semantics of a block, above all regarding the number of arguments, but there are several other differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

Besides the argument passing, I wonder what you would expect from a `return` in the method. It can only behave in `lambda` way...

If you really have to do this, you will need to build your own block, e.g.

```
Proc.new{ a }
```

For a more generic way, you'll have to check the `arity` of the method and pass only the required parameters.

Comment: I imagine it was unlikely because of `return`, `next` and `break`, as a temporary measure I have been either writing methods with splat or making them return a `Proc`. Is there a way to proof it can't be done?

Comment: @michelpm: No proof, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a non-lambda `Proc`, like so:

```ruby
l = lambda {|a,b| puts "a: #{a}, b: #{b}" }
p = proc {|a,b| l.call(a,b) }

l.lambda?
#=> true
l.arity
#=> 2
l.call("hai")
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
l.call("hai", "bai", "weee", "womp", "woo")
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 2)

p.lambda?
#=> false
p.arity
#=> 2
p.call("hai")
#=> a: hai, b: 
p.call("hai", "bai", "weee", "womp", "woo")
#=> a: hai, b: bai
```

Answer (score 0):

## Convert `Lambda` to `Proc`

Here's a work-around that wraps a `lambda` or a `method` call in a `Proc` and uses splat to handle any number of arguments:

```rb
def lambda_to_proc(lambda)
  Proc.new do |*args|
    diff = lambda.arity - args.size
    diff = 0 if diff.negative?
    args = args.concat(Array.new(diff, nil)).take(lambda.arity)

    lambda.call(*args)
  end
end
```

This would always work no matter the number of arguments passed; Extra arguments will be dropped and `nil` will replace the missing arguments.

---

**Example:**

```rb
# lambda with two args
some_lambda = -> (a,b) { [a, b] }

# method with no args
def some_method; "hello!"; end

lambda_to_proc(some_lambda).call(5)
# => [5, nil]

lambda_to_proc(method(:some_method)).call(1,2,3)
# => "hello!"
```

---

<sup>***Note:*** There is no direct way to convert a lambda or a method call to a proc. This is just a workaround and obviously slower than the real deal (because of wrapping one call in another).</sup>

Comment: Keep in mind this doesn't work if your `lambda` can take default arguments. E.g. `some_lambda = -> (a, b = 0) { [a, b] }` raises an `ArgumentError` when called with `lambda_to_proc`. One workaround for this could be to use `lambda.parameters.length` instead of `lambda.arity`.