# method.to_proc doesn't return from enclosed function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to DRY up a Rails controller by extracting a method that includes a guard clause to return prematurely from the controller method in the event of an error. I thought this may be possible using a `to_proc`, like this pure Ruby snippet:

```
def foo(string)
  processed = method(:breaker).to_proc.call(string) 
  puts "This step should not be executed in the event of an error"
  processed
end

def breaker(string)
  begin
   string.upcase!
  rescue
    puts "Well you messed that up, didn't you?"
    return
  end
  string
end
```

My thinking was that having called to_proc on the `breaker` method, calling the early return statement in the `rescue` clause should escape the execution of `foo`. However, it didn't work:

```
2.4.0 :033 > foo('bar')
This step should not be executed in the event of an error
 => "BAR" 
2.4.0 :034 > foo(2)
Well you messed that up, didn't you?
This step should not be executed in the event of an error
 => nil
```

Can anyone please

1. Explain why this doesn't work
2. Suggest a way of achieving this effect?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: as people are wondering why the hell I would want to do this, the context is that I'm trying to DRY up the `create` and `update` methods  in a Rails controller. (I'm trying to be agressive about it as both methods are about 60 LoC. Yuck.) Both methods feature a block like this:

```
some_var = nil
if (some complicated condition)
  # do some stuff
  some_var = computed_value
elsif (some marginally less complicated condition)
  @error_msg =  'This message is the same in both actions.'
  render partial: "show_user_the_error" and return
# rest of controller actions ...
```

Hence, I wanted to extract this as a block, *including the premature return from the controller action*. I thought this might be achievable using a Proc, and when that didn't work I wanted to understand why (which I now do thanks to Marek Lipa).

Comment: 1. It's because `Method#to_proc` returns `lambda`, which behaves more like method in terms of `return` and arguments control.

Comment: Wondered if that might be the case, the name is unfortunate then ...

Comment: Not really, `lambda` *is* a `proc` either, but a different kind.

Comment: Yes, but I lost half an hour of my life that I would not have done had the method been called `to_lambda` :/

Comment: The reason this method is called `to_proc` is it's standard method called internally when you use expressions such as string.each(&:upcase). In this case, it enables to pass this method 'almost' directly as a block, with &method(:breaker).

Comment: @MarekLipka so **is** there a way to turn a method into a non-lambda proc and thus achieve the desired effect of returning from `foo`?

Comment: @MoMolog As far as I know, there isn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197082/how-to-convert-method-or-lambda-to-non-lambda-proc

Comment: @MoMolog in my actual use case, in the event of an error I set an `@error_msg` and rendered a partial to inform the user; so I ended up settling for code that looks like `value = my_function; return if @error_msg; #... rest of function` which is less than ideal but better than the duplication I had.

Comment: Another option is not to rescue the exception (or rescue and raise a specific own exception) and handle it appropriately in the parent method.

Comment: Have you considered a service object rather than putting all your business logic in the controller?

Comment: I'm going to move much of the logic out of the controller, yes; but for this specific instance the code I'm trying to extract is processing the `params` object and conditionally rendering a particular partial as shown in the snippet, so I'm just trying to separate that out and DRY it up.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```rb
def foo(string)
  processed = breaker(string) 
  puts "This step should not be executed in the event of an error"
  processed
rescue ArgumentError
end

def breaker(string)
  begin
    string.upcase!
  rescue
    puts "Well you messed that up, didn't you?"
    raise ArgumentError.new("could not call upcase! on #{string.inspect}")
  end
  string
end
```

After all this is arguably a pretty good use case for an exception.

Comment: Very arguably. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems part of the confusion is that a `Proc` or `lambda` for that matter are distinctly different than a closure (block).

Even if you could convert `Method#to_proc` to a standard `Proc` e.g. `Proc.new` this would simply result in a `LocalJumpError` because the `return` would be invalid in this context.

You can use `next` to break out of a standard `Proc` but the result would be identical to the `lambda` that you have now.

The reason `Method#to_proc` returns a `lambda` is because a `lambda` is far more representative of a method call than a standard `Proc`

For Example:

```
def foo(string)
  string
end 
bar = ->(string) { string } #lambda 
baz = Proc.new {|string| string } 
foo
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
bar.()
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
baz.()
#=> nil
```

Since you are converting a method to a proc object I am not sure why you would also want the behavior to change as this could cause ambiguity and confusion. Please note that for this reason you can not go in the other direction either e.g. `lambda(&baz)` does not result in a `lambda` either as metioned [Here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7314).

Now that we have explained all of this and why it shouldn't really be done, it is time to remember that nothing is impossible in ruby so this would technically work:

```
def foo(string)
  # place assignment in the guard clause
  # because the empty return will result in `nil` a falsey value
  return unless processed = method(:breaker).to_proc.call(string) 
  puts "This step should not be executed in the event of an error"
  processed
end

def breaker(string)
  begin
   string.upcase!
  rescue
    puts "Well you messed that up, didn't you?"
    return
  end
  string
end
```

[Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/QuarterlyCarpalHypermedia)